# Python -- Creating an if statement relating to a key/value pair from an outside variable

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

Within python I am trying to create an if statement which checks if an outside variable is a key connected to a specific value within a dictionary.

I am working with a list of ID's that corresponds to a dictionary of True/False statements relating to those IDs, (for example {22935:False, 29023:True} etc.)

What I originally wanted to do was something like this (sorry I am a bit of a newbie to python):

`if id in dict is True:`

Then I realized that statement is literally impossible, have been searching around and haven't been able to find an answer not sure if I'm just looking up the wrong thing or if what I am looking to do is impossible. Would really appreciate any help with this, Thanks!

Comment: If you want to check whether `id` is linked with the value True in your True/False dictionary, then do `if mydict[id]:`; or `if mydict.get(id):` if you think that the id might not be in the dict at all. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't name the variables dict and id (which are keywords) but just do:

```
if dict[id]:
```

or

```
if dict.get(id):
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i'm understaning perfectly but maybe you want something like this?:

```py
if id in dict:
    if dict.get (id): #this gets the value of if and if it's true you don't need to wring `== True`
        doStuff ()
```

Comment: This would cause an exception. There's no such method as `dict.Value`.

Comment: Yep, sorry i confues the method values for the method get, updated the answer

Comment: If you're using `get` then you don't need the `if id in dict:`.